# Unsure how to modify userDetailsService to allow for custom userDetails but keep datasource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm following [this website](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/-Spring-Security-Customizing-Your-User-and-Authorization-in) to attempt to customise the UserDetails so that I can retrieve more fields regarding the user.

As far as implementing the UserDetails, where I am confused is the UserDetailsService.

At the moment I only have the code for the userDetailsService that is in the website linked above.

I'm just not sure on how to go about doing it.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question? You want to write a custom UserDetailsService?

Comment: yeah, i'm not sure what i need to put in it

Comment: @PeterMularien i've tried to customise the USerDetails and the UserDetailsService but to no prevail

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is with this but my configuration is something like below and works.

```
<beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
    class="yourpackagename.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />
<beans:bean id="myAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="myAuthenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager >
    <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Look at how I have set userdetailservice for the authentication provider and using authentication provider for authentication-manager config.